# Let $f : \mathbb{N} → \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ be given by $f(n) = \{n+1 , n+2 , n+3 , . . . \}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

So i was given a question like this

Let $ f : \Bbb N\to \mathcal P(\Bbb N) $ be given by $f(n) = \{n+1 , n+2 , n+3 , . . . \}$

(a) Is f an injection? Explain

(b) Is f a surjection? Explain.

I assumed that it is in fact an injection because no point is mapped to the same point in the codomain since it is n+1, etc. I do not know how to prove it is a surjection though. I seen previous injective examples proving it is injective by induction, how could that be applied?

Comment: What's your definition of $P(N)$? Power set?

Comment: @Vim the set of all subsets of S, including the empty set and S itself

Comment: Can $f(n)$ ever be a empty set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is also rather general fact that there is no surjection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ (also if you already know that $f$ is injective, surjectivity is impossible since it would imply that $\mathbb{N}$ and it's power set will have the same cardinality which is not true, even for arbitrary sets). But obviously here the situation is so simple that you give rather direct proof (for example none finite set lies in the image of $f$).

Answer (score 0):

$f$ is not surjective. Because there is no such $n\in\Bbb N$ that can be sent to $\{1\}\in\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$.